# Change boot device with multiple Windows 10 installations

Tags: windows, hard-drive, boot, ssd

I installed Windows 10 on 2 devices (HDD and SSD).

The first one was HDD.
Today, I can run Windows 10 on the SSD but only via the Windows boot menu that works only if I boot on HDD first.
The HDD is dying and I would like to run Windows 10 on the SSD directly, without having to go through the old hard drive.

My boot mode is "Legacy".
I add "active" flag on the partition where Windows 10 is installed but I have "no operating system" when I try to boot on the SSD directly.

[Here is a screenshot of my current configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SpBj1.png)

[and my ssd partition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lhEeh.png)

D partition on Disk 0 is my old Windows installation on my old HDD and C partition on Disk 1 is my new Windows installation.

What should I do to make Windows 10 works on the SSD without dependency with the HDD ?

[Bios capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7wJ7D.jpg)
[Bios capture working config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQEmB.jpg)
[Windows Boot Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6BfdX.jpg)
[Bios capture not working config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r4Kiu.jpg)
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UXO2S.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So long as the SSD is empty, you can clone the Windows 10 HDD to the SSD using a software like AOMEI Backupper or Easeus ToDo, remove the old HDD and it will boot up fine.

If you have something like a Windows Preinstallation Environment utility which has a cloning tool, you can use that too. There is a free home version of a software called Lazesoft which you might be able to download to carry out the above tasks.

You need to be careful when you're selecting the source and destination disks as when the process starts, it will wipe the drive on the destination disk so you will lose everything if you have data on it. As both the drivers are the same size, you can select 'Sector-by-Sector' clone, and select 'Same Drive Signature' only if you intend to remove the Hard Drive from there. You should select 'Different Drive Signature' if you intend to use both the drives for some reason simultaneously. Although, please note that it isn't good to continue running the OS from the hard drive especially if you have noticed it has started to become faulty.

But as you are already using it, it may be able to give you enough time to clone the drive over to the new SSD using Lazesoft.

Comment: I have already installed Windows 10 on the SSD and would like to make it works without reinstalling it and without the windows boot menu which works only if I boot on the hdd

Comment: If you have already installed Windows on thr SSD, do you know the type of partition table used? Do you know if the drive was set to GPT or MBR? If the old hard drive was set to Legacy, the partition table for the old drive would be set to MBR. But the new one might have GPT preventing you from booting. Did you try to change the boot order from the BIOS? I'm assuming that is what you have done and it didn't work.

Comment: Yes I change the boot order and it works only if HDD is before SSD. If I try to boot directly on SSD, there is no OS detected.
BIOS is currently configured in "Legacy" but I'm not sure about how the HDD was set and how the SSD was. Is it possible to get this information ?

Comment: In Disk Management, right-click on the Disk that you want to check, then click on Properties, and it will open a new window. Go to the 'Volumes' tab and there you will find Disk Information. There you will see if your Partition Style is MBR (Master Boot Record) or GT (GUID Partition Table).

Comment: It's "secteur de démarrage principal" (MBR) for both

Comment: Would you be able to share the screenshot of the contents of the SSD? Just need to see if the windows files and folders are there. How did you carry out the Windows Installation? Through a USB?

Comment: Added in the original post. Yes it was installed through a usb.
When I tried UEFI in bios, I can't select SSD (only hard drive disk)

Comment: I forget to mention that is a laptop. Could it be a reason that it can't boot directly on added ssd ? It's a MSI GE62 6QF. I can read about that : "Booting from an M.2 drive by using a laptop, which does not come with such a drive is often not supported."

Comment: No, the M.2 drive in this case would be irrelevant due to your Laptop supporting UEFI. Will you be able to Reinstall Windows? If so, try recreating the Windows USB using Rufus, use the UEFI option on Rufus. Make sure to select GPT as well. Change the settings on the BIOS to UEFI and Reinstall the OS onto the SSD. There is almost no reason it shouldn't boot from the SSD after. Although one more setting you should double check is the SATA Configuration on the BIOS. It should be set to AHCI

Comment: No need to clone anything or worry about UEFI. As you installed WIN10 with Legacy BIOS, then continue with it. You need to make the System Reserved partition on the HDD 'inactive', and the SRP on the SSD 'active'. You can do this using the [Diskpart utility in Win10](https://www.remosoftware.com/info/set-active-partition-windows). When you've done this, boot into your BIOS and put the SSD as first boot, then save the settings. Reboot the laptop.

Comment: @PaulBenson I think he might have already done that. I misunderstood his question in terms of the second SSD initially which is why I suggested cloning / reinstalling. He is better of running the new SSD in GPT/UEFI, no? So it doesn't even try to boot into the old SSD? But you're absolutely right about what you said, thank you.

Comment: Thank you for help, following your advise, I finish to find this command : https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/bootsect-command-line-options?view=windows-11
Bootsect seemed to be missing as it resolves the problem !

Answer (score 1):

This boot problem means that the EFI partition is on the HDD
and not on the SSD.

I suggest to physically disconnect the HDD and then
[Run a Startup Repair](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/27649-run-startup-repair-windows-10-a.html).

This will create the EFI partition on the SSD.